# How can I prevent MS Word from reducing the size of my vector equations?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to write "a vector" times "b vector" for making an orthogonal projection formula in MS Word.

I use Equation Mode, but every time I do that, the size of "a vector" is always reduced. What should I do to keep "a vector" the same size as "b vector"?
[image: Image of equation]

Comment: Use LaTeX... (yes, I know it's field-dependent, but I don't understand fields that write equations in Word)

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm not sure why your question has a close vote as "asking what to write or asking for help rewriting a sentence or passage". That's not what you're asking at all. Questions asking how something can be achieved in Microsoft Word are perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: This may not help, but every time Word does something like this I don't like, I press Control+Z, the change is reversed and then I continue. If it is an autocorrect feature, this should work.